# RxJS alternative to Bacon.combineTemplate

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, frp, bacon.js

Can anyone provide a function which can be Bacon.combineTemplate alternative written in RxJS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think it's combineLatest https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/731#issuecomment-105276314 but if you want exactly the same https://github.com/ahomu/rx.observable.combinetemplate

Comment: Thatns, that solved an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solution in the following repo:
https://github.com/ahomu/rx.observable.combinetemplate